# Stdout maxBuffer error while running Gulp task

Tags: node.js, gulp, browserify

I'm setting up a Backbone project and I use `Gulp` to run some tasks. I have encountered a `stdout maxBuffer error` when running my task with `Browserify` and `gulp-compressor`. So, in my `app.js` I have the following:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var _ = require('underscore');
var $ = require('jquery/dist/jquery');
```

Then I've written a task to compile the required libraries into one file, which I will use in my `index.html` like `<script src="dist/bundle.min.js"></script>`, and to minify that file using `gulp-compressor`. Here is the task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserify = require('gulp-browserify'),
    compress = require('gulp-compressor'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
  gulp.src('app/javascripts/app.js')
    .pipe(browserify({
      insertGlobals: true,
      debug: !gulp.env.production
    }))
    .pipe(compress())
    .pipe(rename('bundle.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

But every time I try to run the script it returns me

```
Error: Error: stdout maxBuffer exceeded
```

How could I solve that problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some search in Google the Almighty I found an [answer](https://github.com/steel1990/gulp-compressor/issues/1) on `gulp-compressor` issue tracker. To solve this problem, one should give the following parameters to compress function:

```
// ...
.pipe(compress({
   'executeOptions': {
      maxBuffer: 10000*1024
   }
}))
```

then run `$ npm update` and everything will work!